# Unexpected character when trying to read JSON file with java

Tags: java, json, selenium, testing, logging

Im trying to extract some information from a json file, but i keep getting the error

```
 Unexpected character () at position 0.
```

Ive tried to comment out the non json text but getting

```
Unexpected character (/) at position 0.
```

The code that i am using to try to remove the characters is:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\automation-chrome\\chromelogs1.json");
                String content = IOUtils.toString(fis, Charset.defaultCharset());
                content = content.replaceAll("\\[165", "//");


                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\automation-chrome\\chromelogs2.json");
                IOUtils.write(content, new FileOutputStream("C:\\automation-chrome\\chromelogs2.json"), Charset.defaultCharset());

                Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\automation-chrome\\chromelogs2.json"));

                // A JSON object. Key value pairs are unordered. JSONObject supports java.util.Map interface.
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

                // A JSON array. JSONObject supports java.util.List interface.
                JSONArray companyList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("node");

                // An iterator over a collection. Iterator takes the place of Enumeration in the Java Collections Framework.
                // Iterators differ from enumerations in two ways:
                // 1. Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics.
                // 2. Method names have been improved.
                Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = companyList.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(iterator.next());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Json file looks like:

```
[1653494560.703][INFO]: Starting ChromeDriver 100.0.4896.60 
(6a5d10861ce8de5fce22564658033b43cb7de047-refs/branch-heads/4896@{#875}) on port 32227
[1653494560.703][INFO]: Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security- 
considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1653494561.157][INFO]: [8dec07ea5dd48407fecf90e60411b24c] COMMAND InitSession {
"capabilities": {
  "firstMatch": [ {
     "browserName": "chrome",
     "goog:chromeOptions": {
        "args": [ "start-maximized", "disable-infobars", "--disable-extensions", "-- 
window-size=1920x1080", "--disable-cache", "--disable-application-cache", "--disk-cache- 
size=0", "--dns-prefetch-disable", "--disable-notifications" ],
        "extensions": [  ]
     },
     "pageLoadStrategy": "normal"
  } ]
},
"desiredCapabilities": {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "goog:chromeOptions": {
     "args": [ "start-maximized", "disable-infobars", "--disable-extensions", "--window- 
 size=1920x1080", "--disable-cache", "--disable-application-cache", "--disk-cache-size=0", "--dns-prefetch-disable", "--disable-notifications" ],
     "extensions": [  ]
  },
  "pageLoadStrategy": "normal"
}
}
[1653494650.594][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: DOM.childNodeInserted 
33828E8DE14AF64AED9C57DD86B6EC15 {
"node": {
  "attributes": [ "src", "imsclinicalwdnoting://launch?iss=http%3A%ODA5N...", "style", "display: none;" ],
  "backendNodeId": 301,
  "childNodeCount": 0,
  "localName": "iframe",
  "nodeId": 250,
  "nodeName": "IFRAME",
  "nodeType": 1,
  "nodeValue": ""
},
"parentNodeId": 86,
"previousNodeId": 244
}
```

The idea is to change the file so it can be used as a json file and i can extract the node.attributes.src value and use that as a string. I sthere an easier way to do this like maybe remove all text that isnt part of a json?

Comment: Could be a BOM. Would need to see the raw file (chromelogs1.json) to say for certain. If so, try [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html)

Comment: Your file is not json, the json parser only parses json. Sure, it contains some parts that are json, but the outer framing in the file is not json

Comment: Yea the issue is that its not a pure json, although seems impossible to remove everything except the json values